# Prove that $(\bigcup _{i=1 } ^{\infty } E _i )_x = \bigcup _{i=1 } ^{\infty } (E _i) _x $

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

> Prove  that $\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty E _i\right)_x = \bigcup _{i=1}^\infty (E_i)_x$.

where $E _x= \{y : (x,y) \in E \}$

---

I'm not really content with the following, which is my attempt, since some step may be missing.

$$y \in \left(\bigcup_{i = 1}^\infty E _i\right)_x \iff \exists i\,((x,y) \in E_i) \iff y \in \bigcup_{i = 1}^\infty (E _i)_x $$

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not "missing" per se, but you might want to add the step that: $$\iff\exists i\,((x,y)\in E_i)\iff\underbrace{\exists i\,(y\in (E_i)_x)}_{\text{More explicitly . . .}}\iff \ldots$$

Other than that, it's fine.

Comment: @Michael: I appreciate the spacing added to the quantifier. But the dots were part of the text, not part of the mathematical notation, and have no business being `\ldots`.

Comment: In actual LaTeX, as opposed to MathJax (which is what this is), you can write \dots in text mode and get dots with appropriate spacing.  If you just write three dots, with or without spacing, you get three dots without proper spacing.  I think MathJax adds the spacing in math mode but not in text mode, thus: a+b+c+...+z yields $a+b+c+...+a$, whereas a+b+c\text{...}+z yeilds $a+b+c+\text{...}+z$.  In actual LaTex, the latter is what you get from a+b+c+...+z, which is why writing it that way is a mistake. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: I've edited your answer to include three manually dots with proper spacing, and it seems in text mode in MathJax, that works.

Comment: Wouldn't … (U+2026) be even more correct for text ellipsis?

Comment: @Michael: Yeah, I keep forgetting that until compilation time (which is when I notice these spaces and get annoyed). Mostly because I hardly ever use ellipsis when I write papers. :-P

Answer (score 1):

According to the definition of $E_x$ you have that $$\left(E_i\right)_x=\{y:(x,y)\in E_i\}$$ and therefore $$\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}\left(E_i\right)_x=\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}\{y:(x,y)\in E_i\}\tag{1}$$ while $$\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}E_i\right)_x=\{y:(x,y)\in\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}E_i\}\tag{2}$$ Now you can write in (more) detail (since you were not content with your otherwise correct proof) that if $y \in (1)$ then certainly $y \in (2)$ and vice versa, if $y \in (2)$ then it has to be that $y \in (1)$.